# EF6 CodeFirst Dsde Base de Datos Actualizacion del modelo C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo una solucion de n-capas, dentro del cual tengo separada la DAL de las entidades.

Para esto, estoy usando el modelo denominado **Code First desde Base de Datos**, el cual si bien funciona bastante bien, porque me permite separar las entidades en un proyecto distinto.

Tiene el inconveniente que cuando me actualizan la base de datos (el DBA), me veo en la obligacion, de volver a generar la DAL, y volver a separar las entidades generadas en el otro proyecto.

> ¿Existe alguna forma de automatizar este proceso?.

Estuve viendo **Migrations**, pero eso solo sirve cuando actualizo el modelo (no tengo certeza de que funcione este metodo, si el modelo esta en otro proyecto).

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

CodeFirst desde base de datos no esta pensado para ir actualizando el modelo desde la DDBB, la idea es hacer una primera importación y luego ir modificando las clases y haciendo migraciones.

Si la fuente del modelo es la base de datos yo te recomendaría que cambiases de enfoque y en vez de utilizar CodeFirst desde base de datos uses el modelo EF Designer (no recuerdo el nombre exacto, es el modelo visual).

actualización - explicación de como hacer que cree las entidades en cualquier proyecto:

Con el enfoque Database First puedes especificar donde quieres que se creen las entidades modificando la plantilla T4 que usa el archivo EDMX.

La manera mas fácil de hacerlo es llevarte el *.Context.t4 a la solución donde quieras almacenar las entidades, luego editas el T4 y en el apartado

```
const string inputFile = @"Model1.edmx";
```

Especificas la ruta al EDMX.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Tutorial ModelFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205424(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: te refieres a DataBase First :)

Comment: si.. databasefirst, el tema es que dbf genera un objeto edmx, en el cual el modelo queda "enganchado" al contexto en el mismo proyecto, y yo los tengo separados

Comment: Hola @LuisGabrielFabres te he actualizado la entrada con una pequeña explicación de como dejar las entidades en cualquier otro proyecto.

Comment: Hola David, mira, el problema que se da ahi, es que para EF6, ya no estan disponibles las herramientas de Self-tracking entity generator, la cual es necesaria, porque si intentas arrastrar el archivo .TT, el visual studio no te permite hacer eso, entonces la unica opcion que habia en EF5, era borrar el .TT, y crear uno con esta herramienta. que lamentablemente para EF6 ya no existe. No se si tu tendras mas info al respecto, o si es posible hacer esto de otra manera?

Comment: Hola,
Para comprobar que todo sigue funcionando como la ultima vez que lo probé, he creado un par de proyectos y he realizado la prueba con EF6 sin ningún problema, tal como viene visual studio 2015, creas un nuevo ADO.NET EDM, este EDM crea el archivo context.tt y el model.tt, si arrastras el model.tt a otro proyecto y lo modificas para que use la ruta del edmx genera las entidades sin problema.

Comment: Excelente David, no había reparado en esa manera de realizar el proceso. me sirvio bastante la ayuda. gracias